How to override tailwind config file for input type text focus
I have used a multiple select dropdown from react-select package in my project. Now the cursor in the input field is getting css from tailwind base classes and I am not able to override it from my Select component which I am getting from my react-select package. I tried to override the tailwind.config.js file but no success. This is my below code of tailwind.config
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */

const defaultTheme = require("tailwindcss/defaultTheme");

module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    input: {
      focus: {
        boxShadow: "none",
      },
    },
    extend: {
      container: {
        center: true,
        padding: "15px",
      },
      fontFamily: {
        sans: ["Inter var", ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [require("@tailwindcss/forms")],
};


Even though my outline is set to zero but because of bow-shadow property I am getting a border around my cursor. When I tried inspecting it from the developer's console and I set box-shadow: none it goes.
Can anyone please help me to achieve it.

You have to add
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  important: true,

to make sure your tailwind styles can override.
Also you might have to specify for the appropriate components the className in react-select, e.g.:
<Select
  classNames={{
    control: ({ isFocused }) =>
      isFocused ? "border-blue-600 shadow-none" : "border-grey-300",

